# Create an SSH connection via wireless router

Tags: ssh

I would like to create an SSH connection with a wireless router I got from BT. Any Idea how I can do this?. I want to use this SSH connection to connect to my home server.

I want to connect from outside my home to the wireless router that is connected to my home server with Linux based operating system.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This needs to be clarified. What system are you on? Do you want a connection specifically _from_ the router to the home server? Or do you just want to connect from a computer from _within_ the network inside your router? Or do you want to connect via SSH _to_ the router for administration purposes? Perhaps an answer to "Why do you want to connect?" will suffice, so people who want to help can know what you are really asking.

Comment: I got a MAC laptop, a router that I got from my Internet provider that is connected to my home server (runs Ubuntu) through a cable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that you want to connect to the home server from outside your home, correct? You don't really connect via SSH to the router for this; you just tell the router to pass the connection on to the home server. If this is the case, read on. If not, clarify the question even more.

You will have to tell the router to pass incoming traffic on the SSH port on to your internal server. This is usually called "port forwarding" or similar. See Google or perhaps http://www.portforward.com/ for specific guides for your router on how to accomplish this. It is usually handled via some web interface that you see when you enter the routers internal IP address (usually 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1) in a browser from within the home network.

Forward e.g. port 22 for the TCP protocol (the standard SSH port) from your router to your home server. After this is done, and you have an SSH server running on your server, you can just connect via SSH to your external IP (which is "owned" by the router), which will forward the connection to the server.